# "uwamp" openssl extension Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, uwamp

I'm trying to install composer on my windows 7 using uwamp but i'm getting this message : the openssl extension is missing from the php version.
I opened php_uwamp.ini and I did a copy and named to php.ini and changed  php_uwamp.ini and php.ini to

```
;extension_dir = "ext"
```

to

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

and

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

in php bin\php\php-5.6.30-Win32-VC11-x86 and \bin\apache. But still having the same error message.

Comment: forget to mention that i did a  copy php_uwamp.ini and named to php.ini in the same folder

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Uwamp 3.1.0 and PHP 5.6.18 on Windows 7 x64.

Part of the solution is already answered here [How to enable 'openssl' in UwAmp CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892831/how-to-enable-openssl-in-uwamp-cli), but there is more :)

The problem with Uwamp (if we don't mention that they should already answer this thread, not us, the users :) ) is because it is using that custom **php_uwamp.ini** file and "normal" **php.ini** is missing from **../bin/php/php-xxx/** (still used by many PHP tools) and there is actually the php.ini file in **../bin/apache/php.ini** file so I have solved the problem by using extensions path from that file.

The problem was the relative path of **ext** folder, so just put the absolute path and the problem should be solved (as is for me).

So to write exact steps:

1. Locate Your  UwAmp PHP "bin" folder of used PHP version (*example C:/Uwamp/bin/php/php-5.6.18/*)
2. Locate "custom Uwamp" **php_uwamp.ini** file and duplicate it in same folder as php.ini
3. Open that duplicated php.ini file and locate the following line:

> ;extension_dir = "ext" 
>   or 
>   ; extension_dir = "{PHPEXTPATH}"

3. Now locate other already existing **php.ini** file in UwAmp Apache "bin" folder ((example C:/Uwamp/bin/apache/php.ini) and find the line with absolute path (example)

> ; extension_dir = "C:/UwAmp/bin/php/php-5.6.18/ext"

and use it into yours new file C:/UwAmp/bin/php/php-5.6.18/php.ini by uncommenting it and of course check is that absolute path correct.

So now your php.ini file in PHP "bin" folder should be something like this:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "{PHPEXTPATH}" 
; On windows:
;extension_dir = "ext"
extension_dir = "C:/UwAmp/bin/php/php-5.6.18/ext"
```

Comment: I don't have that php in bin in apache